# Give ranks to a list without sorting in C

Tags: c, rank

I try to give the rank to the data, but the result is not what i expected.My for {} is as below :

```
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
{
    int curRank=1;

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)  
                              //  add x[i] to list, need to update the ranks. 
    {
        if (x[i] > x[j]) 
        {                      // Update rank of x[i]
            curRank++;
        } 
        else 
        {                  // A number smaller than x[j] has appeared. Update rank of x[j]
            rank[j]++;
        }
    }

    rank[i]=curRank;
    printf("%lf %d\n", x[i],rank[i]);
}
```

And the result turns out like this:

```
30.000000 1
71.510000 2
 3.300000 1
87.440000 4
53.420000 3
63.160000 4
89.100000 7
25.750000 2
.......
```

Clearly, it is wrong. Could anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Edit the question and give minimum understandable code here so that others can look through and you may get help,

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm works, but the ranking isn't complete after all values have been processed. Therefore, you can't print the ranks as you go. You must print the ranks after your algorihm is done in a separate loop:

```
    double x[8] = {30, 71.51, 3.3, 87.44, 53.42, 63.16, 89.1, 25.75};
    int rank[8] = {0};
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int curRank = 1;

        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (x[i] > x[j]) {
                curRank++;
            } else {
                rank[j]++;
            }
        }

        rank[i] = curRank;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%lf %d\n", x[i], rank[i]);
    }
```

Comment: And I have an additional question. It there are two same numbers, which means the data has ties, take 2 of 3.3 for example. Then the rank of these two 3.3 will be 1.5, how can I deal with it? I tried to add an if condition before the else {}, but it does not work. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not aware of a nomenclature that uses rational numbers for ranks. The current code assigns 1 to the first occurrence of 3.3 and 2 to the second. That reflects that rank means position in a sorted array. Sometimes, equal elements share a rank and subsequent ranks then leave a gap, e.g. ranks 1, 1, 3, 4, ... for an array with two occurrences. Off the top of my head I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: You could always make a second pass and collate equal values.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try.