# How can I display a student's rank, withouth the rank being in descending order

Tags: java

I have made a program that gets the averages of 4 students from 5 diff subjects.

their averages would be:

```
student a = 87.33
student b = 82.53
student c = 86.13
student d = 87.33
```

Now I want to rank them based on their averages. The output that I wanted should look like

```
student a = 87.13  2
student b = 82.53  4
student c = 86.13  3
student d = 87.33  1
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: Well, that's sorting, isn't it?

Comment: Wasn't it the question, if you can do this without sorting? Or do you want to have the same order for your students and just somehow (even with sorting another array) calculating the ranking? In latter case you can use those approaches.

Comment: Here is the answer in C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595441/give-ranks-to-a-list-without-sorting-in-c

Comment: @JanosVinceller What a silly answer. sort-a-copy is faster and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible without sorting, more or less by definition. (I guess you can go out of your way to invent an algorithm that does this without reordering things, but you're just reinventing sorting by another name then).

But you can, of course, **copy** the list of students you have, sort that list, then assign each student a rank by just iterating the sorted list, then tossing the sorted list:

```
List<Student> copy = new ArrayList<Student>(input);
copy.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder().reversed());
for (int i = 0; i < copy.size(); i++) copy.get(i).setRank(i + 1);

// input has not been changed at all; only the copy has been sorted.
```

Comment: @PoorGamer okay - well, this still answers your question, no?

Comment: I'm currently trying this approach but what should I put in setRank and how should I print the ranks? Also I'm making this a function (sorry for being stupid :(   )

Answer (score 0):

You definetly should do sorting. You could use special data structure to do so. E.g. you can use `PriorityQueue`:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
            new Student('a', 87.13),
            new Student('b', 82.53),
            new Student('c', 86.13),
            new Student('d', 87.33));
    Map<Character, Integer> ranks = ranks(students);

    for (Student student : students)
        System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "student %s = %.2f %d\n", student.id, student.avg, ranks.get(student.id));
}

private static Map<Character, Integer> ranks(List<Student> students) {
    Queue<Student> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Student.SORT_BY_AVG_DESC);
    queue.addAll(students);

    int rank = 1;
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    while (!queue.isEmpty())
        map.put(queue.remove().id, rank++);

    return map;
}

static class Student {

    public static final Comparator<Student> SORT_BY_AVG_DESC =
            Comparator.comparingDouble((ToDoubleFunction<Student>)student -> student.avg).reversed();

    private final char id;
    private double avg;

    public Student(char id, double avg) {
        this.id = id;
        this.avg = avg;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
student a = 87.13 2
student b = 82.53 4
student c = 86.13 3
student d = 87.33 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. Essentially you need to sort the ranks based on the score.  Note that this doesn't cater to students with identical scores who may be ranked the same.  The ranks are sorted in reverse order based on the score.

```
List<StudentClass> students =
        List.of(new StudentClass("studenta", 87.33),
                new StudentClass("studentb", 82.53),
                new StudentClass("studentc", 86.13),
                new StudentClass("studentd", 87.33));

Integer[] ranks = {1,2,3,4};

Arrays.sort(ranks,
        (a,b)->Double.compare(students.get(b-1).getScore(),students.get(a-1).getScore()));

for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(students.get(i) + " " + ranks[i]);
}
```

Prints

```
studenta 87.33  1
studentb 82.53  4
studentc 86.13  3
studentd 87.33  2
```

StudentClass declaration.

```
class StudentClass {
    String name;
    double score;
    
    public StudentClass(String name, double score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }
    
    public double getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s ", name, score);
    }
}
```